# SP 2013 - People picker with local accounts

Tags: 2013, people-picker

I'm using SharePoint Foundation 2013 on a test server.

This server is not in a domain, it is just the single server with its SQL (I know this is all bad, but just developing some things on SP) and about 5 local accounts (I mean Windows accounts).

I've used Powershell to set the SPPeoplePickerSettings.AllowLocalAccount property to true, thinking it could be the correct solution. Powershell script worked fine (no errors).

I've restarted the server and SharePoint services, but people pickers in my SharePoint are keeping to show "No result".

Is it possibile to show local windows account in people picker?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to `AllowLocalAccount` requiring Windows authentication (Classic auth). As the default for SharePoint 2013 and above uses Claims authentication by default, the code path to enable this setting is ignored. On the `SPUtility.ResolvePrincipalInternal` method (there are other methods that resolve accounts as well, but they're very similar), we see:

```
        bool flag2 = alwaysAddWindowsResolver || (webApplication == null);
        if (!flag2 && (webApplication != null))
        {
            if ((web == null) && urlZone.HasValue)
            {
                flag2 = webApp.IisSettings[urlZone.Value].AuthenticationMode == AuthenticationMode.Windows;
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (SPIisSettings settings in webApplication.IisSettings.Values)
                {
                    if (settings.AuthenticationMode == AuthenticationMode.Windows)
                    {
                        flag2 = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (flag2)
[...]
                if (SPUserUtility.IsAllowedAccount(domainName, web, webApp))
                {
                    bySidResolver = new SPActiveDirectoryPrincipalBySIDResolver(web, (web == null) ? webApp : web.Site.WebApplication, domainName, ntAccountName, binaryForm, sidTypeInvalid, false);
            }
```

So we can see `flag2` is only set to `true` when the `AuthenticationMode` is set to `Windows`. In a Claims-based Web Application, the `AuthenticationMode` is `Forms`.

Additionally, installing SharePoint 2013 in a Workgroup is unsupported per [KB2764086](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2764086/certain-microsoft-sharepoint-server-2013-installation-scenarios-are-no).